# Wie nennt man Gegenstände, die typisch für die Mitglieder einer bestimmten Gruppe sind?

Tags: single-word-request, vocabulary

Es gibt da einen bildungssprachlichen Ausdruck der mir einfach nicht einfallen will. Stattdessen muss ich immer an "Insignien" denken.

Bei dem Wort das ich suche geht es nicht unbedingt um Gegenstände die ausschließlich dazu getragen werden um Gruppenzugehörigkeit auszudrücken, den Träger aber trotzdem relativ eindeutig einer Gruppe zuordnen.

> Beispiel 1: Auf dem Nachttisch lagen eine Baseballcap mit
>   Hanfblatt-Emblem, eine Casio Uhr aus echt goldfarbenem Plastik, ein
>   Fidget-Spinner, eine E-Zigarette und eine angebrochene Dose Red Bull:
>   die neuen [] der geistigen Provinz.
>
> Beispiel 2: Reflektorjacke, Fahrradhelm und Hosenklammer sind die []
>   des Fahrradpendlers.

Comment: Meinst du Paraphernalien? Das bezieht sich eher auf Kulte, aber im übertragenen Sinn passt es vielleicht.

Comment: @Philipp Ich kenne eigentlich nur Paraphernalien als eine Art Mitgift.

Comment: @tofro Ich meine, man verwendet das für Kultgegenstände, aber nicht nur religiöser Art, z. B. gibt es in China eine ganze Industrie, die Mao-Paraphernalien an Touristen verkauft. Deshalb etwa Folgendes: »Reflektorjacke, Fahrradhelm und Hosenklammer sind die Paraphernalien des Fahrradpendlers.« Darunter würde ich verstehen, dass der Autor des Satzes die Fahrradpendler als beinahe fanatische Gruppe betrachtet, die sich durch besonderes Verhalten auszeichnet (z. B. Rücksichtslosigkeit im Straßenverkehr oder die Ansicht, moralisch überlegen zu sein).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besonders zu Beispiel 2 passt natürlich sehr gut:

> Reflektorjacke, Fahrradhelm und Hosenklammer sind die ***Uniform*** des Fahrradpendlers.

Aber Symbol, Zeichen, Kennzeichen passen ebenfalls gut.

Soll es bildungssprachlicher sein dann nehme man Totem, Fetisch, Stammeszeichen, Chiffre, Attribute,  Erkennungszeichen, Merkmale, Charakteristikum, Signum oder Eigenheit, Abzeichen.

> … die neuen ***Wahrzeichen*** der geistigen Provinz.

Comment: ***Wahrzeichen*** ist schön! Mit der _Uniform_ bin ich nicht so 100%ig konform.

Answer (score 3):

**Markenzeichen**

In *Duden – Das große Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache* findet man für Markenzeichen neben der ersten Bedeutung *(in bestimmter grafischer Form gestaltetes u. geschütztes Zeichen, mit dem alle Artikel einer Marke gekennzeichnet werden; Warenzeichen)* noch die zweite Bedeutung *etwas, was für jemanden oder eine Sache bezeichnend, typisch ist.*

> bunte Hemden sind sein Markenzeichen
>
> Der Konsens mit denjenigen, die Arbeitsplätze schaffen, muss zum Markenzeichen der Regierung werden

Answer (score 2):

> klassische Utensilien

passt, denke ich, ganz gut.

> Insignien

ist bildungssprachlicher, passt aber nicht ganz so gut, wenn es nicht spöttisch gemeint sein soll.

Comment: Ich will gar nicht so genau wissen was _U**n**tensilien_ sind :3

Comment: Und wenn wir ganz beim Deutsch bleiben wollen, passt auch _klassische Gebrauchsgegenstände_ finde ich.

Answer (score 0):

Also ich hatte mal nach "Kennzeichen" gesucht, und auf [dieser Website](https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/kennzeichen.php) die folgenden passenden Begriffe gefunden:

- Emblem
- Parabel
- Symbol
- Attribut

Ich denke, die passen alle ganz gut.

Answer (score 0):

Wenn es Singular sein darf:

> Equipment

Aber auch einen Plural habe ich im Angebot:

> Devotionalien